# Alternatives to Google Website Optimizer

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing, google-website-optimizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good resources for doing A/B testing of a website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-are-some-good-resources-for-doing-a-b-testing-of-a-website)

What (affordable) alternatives are there to Google Website Optimizer for A/B and multivariate tests?

The pro's with GWO are basically that its free and that it integrates with Google Analytics.

The cons: The relative high time cost of setting up a test.

Some alternatives I've seen so far:

- [Optimizely.com](http://www.optimizely.com/)
- [VisualWebsiteOptimizer.com](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/)
- Genetify ([wiki.github.com/gregdingle/genetify/](http://wiki.github.com/gregdingle/genetify/)) Free, open-source, but seems like there's no developer community committed to the project.

Comment: You might check this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-are-some-good-resources-for-doing-a-b-testing-of-a-website

Comment: Yes, close enough to a duplicate for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mighty list has a selection of A/B & MVT tools:

http://www.whichmvt.com/

No relationship with either the list compilers or any of the listed vendors (we have out own in-house MVT tool).

Answer (score 0):

I have used GetClicky.com for this. They have the ability to set goals and have user actions trigger the goals. They also have some nice analytics.

I found this much simpler than Google's Website Optimizer.

Answer (score -1):

Just AB testing you can do with the new Google Analytics Content Experiments but if you want MVT you can look on [Convert.com](http://www.convert.com).

Yep I am founder ... plug